# Fitnesse: Connection Reset

Tags: fitnesse

I am running tests in fitnesse with the following issue occurring:

```
Internal Exception:
Connection Reset
```

Does anyone know why this is occurring and how to fix it?

SuiteSetup contains file:

```
!define TEST_SYSTEM {fit}
!define COMMAND_PATTERN {%m -r fitnesse.fitserver.FitServer, C:\GrowthEdition.QA\fitnesse\fitSharp\fit.dll %p}
!define TEST_RUNNER {C:\GrowthEdition.QA\fitnesse\fitSharp\Runner.exe}

!define COLLAPSE_SETUP {true}
!define COLLAPSE_TEARDOWN {true}
!define MANUALLY_START_TEST_RUNNER_ON_DEBUG {debug}

!path C:\GrowthEdition.QA\fitnesse\fitSharp\*.dll
!path C:\Users\rdixit\Documents\Visual~3\Projects\LearningTestAutomation\LearningTestAutomation\bin\x86\Debug\LearningTestAutomation.dll
```

Comment: More info is needed than that.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you started Fitnesse server ok. And you are working on a Fitnesse wiki page and your test fixture.
The connection reset happens when your test is trying to connect a web server but it's failed. You may need to debug your test to see what it is connecting.
I put a guideline link for reference.
https://vikashazrati.wordpress.com/2007/12/05/remote-debugging-fitnesse-with-eclipse/

Comment: This should be comment.